# Why does Android Studio never show layout decorations when I open it?

Tags: android-studio

As you can see in the image below, every time I open a project in Android Studio, the **layout decorations** option is deselected. How can I have it selected for default?

[image: Layout Decorations setting]

Comment: Just tried an was unable to reproduce that behavior. Try to update Android Studio.

Comment: Tried to update and tried to uninstall, but the problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

look on the top left of **constraintLayout** that you currently open, click on the eye icon and then click ***Show Layout Decorations***. then you will be able to see it. but i don't know how to access it.

Comment: The problem is that every time I open Android Studio the layout decorations are disabled, I was asking how can I enable them by default.

Answer (score 0):

I think is not possible. I never see about that the solution